# Xbox 360 Wireless Headset connection issue

Tags: xbox-360

For some reason, my Xbox 360 wireless headset keeps disconnecting and reconnecting itself at very random moments. My headsets battery is full and I am in a direct visual to my Xbox within a short distance away. I have even bought a second wireless headset to test out and it still has the same issue.

I know that other people have had this issue because I have seen it on different forums ([Example](http://www.gamespot.com/pages/forums/show_msgs.php?topic_id=25709208)) but I was wondering if anyone has maybe found a solution for it yet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming you are using a wireless Controller as well. I have had so many issues with wireless controllers and headsets that I now use a wired controller and a wired headset. However my wife uses a Turtle Beach headset and a wireless controller and has never had an issue. They are a little expensive but Turtle Beach headsets are really good.

Comment: So you don't have this problem when you use a wired controller while still using the wireless headset?

Comment: Correct, but i still use a wired headset myself just because I got tired of wasting batteries or charging them all the time. I still have the original wired headset that came with my XBox and it works great with a wired controller. I'm not sure what the exact issue is but it is definitely the wireless controller that has the issue.

Comment: You may have a device in your home that operates on a similar frequency. Cordless phones, bluetooth devices, garage door openers, and even cheap microwaves can all interfere with wireless headsets/controllers.

Answer (score 0):

There is a possiblility that your mic input on your controller is playing up. I found on one of my controllers that I have to push the connection upwards to get it working. Basically, If your controller thinks there is a wired mic in, it will take over the wireless. Push your thumb gently against the connection while in a party to see if this is the case. Take caution as you could do damage to the controller if the mic is plugged in. Your risk, though I fixed this issue by placing a plastic(NOT METAL PEOPLE, electricity) spoon under the connection pushing it up, cut the rest of the spoon off and taped it. I can now use my preferred wired controller with my wireless headset. Risky, maybe. If you have a few controllers, use a different one, and if it keeps happening, it's most likely battery on the wireless headset, or if it's a bluetooth/xbox one, ensure the switch between the two is set to Xbox.